# StandardScalar instead of normalize in parameter_grid

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to pass `normalize` in parameter search to pass it to GridSearchCV.
I'm getting a warning that normalize is depreciated and that I should use StandardScalar instead.
I can't just add StandardScalar to the pipeline because that would apply it all the time when I want it to be applied once and not applied the second time.

This is my code:

```
        'params': {
        'normalize': [True, False]
        }
```

How can I use `StandardScalar` here instead of `normalize`?

Answer (score 2):

Just incorporate `StandardScaler` into your pipeline, and control its parameters

```
class sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler(*, copy=True, 
                                           with_mean=True, with_std=True)
```

By setting `with_mean=False` and `with_std=False` you will get no normalisation, and setting both to true - you get whitening.

Quote from [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> The standard score of a sample x is calculated as:
>
> z = (x - u) / s
>
> where u is the mean of the training samples or zero if
> with_mean=False, and s is the standard deviation of the training
> samples or one if with_std=False.